# Conservar Valor en Input Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net, materialize

Estoy trabajando con Materialize 1.0.0 y ayer formule una pregunta de cómo separar el datepicker en 3 campos select, la cual me dieron solución.

Actualmente tengo otro problema que no logro solucionar o no tengo los conocimientos suficientes.

Necesito que la fecha que quede en el datepicker se conserve porque los 3 campos SELECT estarán ocultos.

También hay un backend ya construido en VB.NET que hace un CRUD y cuando guarda se lleva es lo 3 valores de los 3 selects.

hay alguna forma de que pueda conservar la fecha en el mismo campo.

Dejo el código

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <title>Dirección</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- AÑO-->
            <div class="input-field col s4">
                <select id="anio"></select>
                <label>Año</label>
            </div>
            <!-- MES -->
            <div class="input-field col s4">
                <select id="mes"></select>
                <label>Mes</label>
            </div>
            <!-- DIÁ -->
            <div class="input-field col s4">
                <select id="dia"></select>
                <label>Diá</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fecha">
            <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="fecha" placeholder="fecha completa">
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        M.AutoInit();
    </script>

    <script>
        $('#fecha').on('change', function () {
            var Fecha = $('#fecha').val();
            var FechaNueva = new Date(Fecha)
            $('#anio').append(new Option(FechaNueva.getFullYear(), FechaNueva.getFullYear())).val(FechaNueva.getFullYear());
            $('#mes').append(new Option(FechaNueva.getMonth() + 1, FechaNueva.getMonth() + 1)).val(FechaNueva.getMonth() + 1);
            $('#dia').append(new Option(FechaNueva.getDate(), FechaNueva.getDate())).val(FechaNueva.getDate());
            $('select').formSelect();
        })


        let mostrando = document.getElementById('fecha').value;
        document.getElementById('fecha').innerHTML = mostrando;
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Ya he intentato usando innerHTML para asignar un valor pero no se conserva.

Cualquier aporte me ayudara mucho.

Comment: A que te refieres con conservar la misma fecha?

Comment: No se entiende bien la pregunta. Parece sin embargo que lo que necesitas es algo como los atributos `data-*` que sirven para guardar información extra en elemento. Por ejemplo si pones en un solo elemento: `data-fechaOne="Fecha1" data-fechaTwo="Fecha2"  data-fechaThree="Fecha3"` tendrás tres valores distintos en un mismo elemento. Esos valores se pueden cambiar, recuperar, enviar, etc. De todos modos no es clara tu pregunta.

Comment: Nesecito es que el dato que queda en el input de datepicker se conserve, asi se recargue la página

Answer (score 0, accepted):

javascript trabaja de lado del cliente y mantener el valor de las variables pues es imposible ya que el hecho de recargar es volver a iniciar todo el código.

Pero puedes utilizar "cookies" (es una pequeña información almacenada en el navegador) que te ayudarán a mantener los valores.

Nota : Para que entiendas lo mejor que sucede con los métodos de las "cookies" te invito a leer la siguiente página : https://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html que te da una explicación a fondo.

En el código adjunto te dejo los comentarios explicando de que es lo que sucede.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <title>Dirección</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- AÑO-->
            <div class="input-field col s4">
                <select id="anio"></select>
                <label>Año</label>
            </div>
            <!-- MES -->
            <div class="input-field col s4">
                <select id="mes"></select>
                <label>Mes</label>
            </div>
            <!-- DIÁ -->
            <div class="input-field col s4">
                <select id="dia"></select>
                <label>Diá</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fecha">
            <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="fecha" placeholder="fecha completa">
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        // ------ START métodos de cookies ----- 

        function createCookie(name,value,days) {
            if (days) {
                var date = new Date();
                date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
                var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
            }
            else var expires = "";
            document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
        }

        function readCookie(name) {
            var nameEQ = name + "=";
            var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
            for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
                var c = ca[i];
                while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
                if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
            }
            return null;
        }

        function eraseCookie(name) {
            createCookie(name,"",-1);
        }
        // ------ END métodos de cookies ----- 

        // -- Creamos el método que se va encargar de asignar el valor a tu "input#fecha" -- 
        function setValue(){

            var _date = readCookie("pickedDate");
            if(_date != null){
                console.log(_date);
                //Asignamos el valor de la cookie
                document.getElementById('fecha').value = _date; 

            } else { 

                //La primera vez que se inicia el método es un hecho que no
                //va existir la cookie y verás este mensaje despues
                //de realizar el onchange este mensaje ya no deberia aparecer
                alert("Aun no hay cookies"); 
            }
        }

        M.AutoInit();
    </script>

    <script>
        $('#fecha').on('change', function () {

            var Fecha = $('#fecha').val();
            var FechaNueva = new Date(Fecha)
            $('#anio').append(new Option(FechaNueva.getFullYear(), FechaNueva.getFullYear())).val(FechaNueva.getFullYear());
            $('#mes').append(new Option(FechaNueva.getMonth() + 1, FechaNueva.getMonth() + 1)).val(FechaNueva.getMonth() + 1);
            $('#dia').append(new Option(FechaNueva.getDate(), FechaNueva.getDate())).val(FechaNueva.getDate());

            $('select').formSelect();

            //Borramos la cookie cada que realices un "on change"  
            eraseCookie("pickedDate"); 

            //Obtenemos el valor de la fecha asignada
            let mostrando = document.getElementById('fecha').value; 

            //Colocamos el valor a la cookie
            createCookie("pickedDate",mostrando,1); 

        });


        //Por último llamamos al método cada que recargues
        //la página que va validar si hay valores en la cookie

        setValue();

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

La primera vez que se ejecuta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después de hacer el "on change" y recargar el sitio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos!